# How to install pillow from conda without downgrading Python and without building pillow from source

Tags: anaconda, python-imaging-library, conda

I'm using a miniconda on Ubuntu 19.04, installed by normal user, not via sudo to keep it separate from the system-installed packages. All of my conda packages are up-to-date via:

```
condaw update -n envpython3 --all
```

So now Python 3.7.4 is the version of Python installed in that conda env.

Looking on the docs for pillow at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html I see that version 7 seems to be the latest (but version 6 might do just fine as it supports 3.7.x  but the "x" here is of concern in this question; read on):

```
Pillow is supported on the following Python versions
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|Python               |2.4|2.5|2.6|2.7|3.2|3.3|3.4|3.5|3.6|3.7|
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow < 2.0.0       |Yes|Yes|Yes|Yes|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow 2.x - 3.x     |   |   |Yes|Yes|Yes|Yes|Yes|Yes|   |   |
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow 4.x           |   |   |   |Yes|   |Yes|Yes|Yes|Yes|   |
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow 5.0.x - 5.1.x |   |   |   |Yes|   |   |Yes|Yes|Yes|   |
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow 5.2.x - 5.4.x |   |   |   |Yes|   |   |Yes|Yes|Yes|Yes|
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow 6.x           |   |   |   |Yes|   |   |   |Yes|Yes|Yes|
|---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|Pillow >= 7.0.0      |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |Yes|Yes|Yes|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I went to install the "pillow" package using conda, it says that it is going to "DOWNGRADE" a lot of packages, even Python back to 3.7.1:

```
$ condaw install -n envpython3 -c anaconda pillow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/brentg/conda/Ubuntu.19.04.miniconda3/envs/envpython3

  added / updated specs:
    - pillow


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2019.5.15  |                1         134 KB  anaconda
    certifi-2019.6.16          |           py37_1         156 KB  anaconda
    freetype-2.9.1             |       h8a8886c_1         822 KB  anaconda
    jpeg-9b                    |       habf39ab_1         247 KB  anaconda
    libpng-1.6.37              |       hbc83047_0         364 KB  anaconda
    libtiff-4.0.10             |       h2733197_2         604 KB  anaconda
    olefile-0.46               |           py37_0          48 KB  anaconda
    openssl-1.1.1              |       h7b6447c_0         5.0 MB  anaconda
    pillow-6.1.0               |   py37h34e0f95_0         635 KB  anaconda
    zstd-1.3.7                 |       h0b5b093_0         887 KB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         8.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  freetype           anaconda/linux-64::freetype-2.9.1-h8a8886c_1
  jpeg               anaconda/linux-64::jpeg-9b-habf39ab_1
  libpng             anaconda/linux-64::libpng-1.6.37-hbc83047_0
  libtiff            anaconda/linux-64::libtiff-4.0.10-h2733197_2
  olefile            anaconda/linux-64::olefile-0.46-py37_0
  pillow             anaconda/linux-64::pillow-6.1.0-py37h34e0f95_0
  zstd               anaconda/linux-64::zstd-1.3.7-h0b5b093_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1c-h7b6447c_1 --> anaconda::openssl-1.1.1-h7b6447c_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates                                 pkgs/main --> anaconda
  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> anaconda

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  cffi                                1.12.3-py37h2e261b9_0 --> 1.11.5-py37he75722e_1
  chardet                                   3.0.4-py37_1003 --> 3.0.4-py37_1
  cryptography                           2.7-py37h1ba5d50_0 --> 2.4.2-py37h1ba5d50_0
  libedit                           3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0 --> 3.1.20170329-h6b74fdf_2
  libgcc-ng                                9.1.0-hdf63c60_0 --> 8.2.0-hdf63c60_1
  libstdcxx-ng                             9.1.0-hdf63c60_0 --> 8.2.0-hdf63c60_1
  pip                                         19.2.2-py37_0 --> 18.1-py37_0
  pyopenssl                                   19.0.0-py37_0 --> 18.0.0-py37_0
  pysocks                                      1.7.0-py37_0 --> 1.6.8-py37_0
  python                                   3.7.4-h265db76_1 --> 3.7.1-h0371630_7
  requests                                    2.22.0-py37_0 --> 2.21.0-py37_0
  setuptools                                  41.0.1-py37_0 --> 40.6.3-py37_0
  sqlite                                  3.29.0-h7b6447c_0 --> 3.26.0-h7b6447c_0
  urllib3                                     1.24.2-py37_0 --> 1.24.1-py37_0
  wheel                                       0.33.4-py37_0 --> 0.32.3-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.

$
```

However, I was able to just use pip from that same conda env to install it without complaint:

```
$ pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/da/2bd281c875686230eabc13d20ab590ea617563b0e746abfb0698c4d5b645/Pillow-6.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1MB)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-6.1.0
$
```

However, I believe that might be a bad thing to do, as I speculate that there are a lot of other packages that conda will manage that pip will not handle adequately (hence why I prefer conda over pip most of the time).

Thus, the question is this: How do I use the latest version of conda-managed pillow *without* downgrading any other packages such as Python, and without building pillow from source?

Ideally I would work around this *without* also having to have a completely separate conda env just for the scripts that use pillow, which is a maintenance burden (e.g., I envision this happening to me: "Dang it! I thought I installed pillow already! Ah no, it is in that other conda env. Sigh.")  But if that *is* the answer then so be it, but I still want to know why Pillow (or something it is dependent upon) seemingly is forcing a downgrade of python.

(Also, the output above gives no indication as to why it needed to downgrade the packages, and I can only imagine it is because pillow somehow requires 3.7.1 when I want to use the latest version of .)

Comment: Yeah, mixing in PyPI is generally a bad idea, especially if you ever plan to update any of the packages in it, which it sounds like is your intention (see ["Using Pip in a Conda Environment"](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)). Have you checked other channel options (e.g., `conda-forge`)? It may also be worth [pinning Python](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) to see what the solver does.

Comment: @merv I did try `conda-forge` but came up empty.  Your provided link to ["Using Pip in a Conda Environment"](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) does give me the answer that I've already concluded: I have to have a separate conda env to proceed. Its a hassle but until this package is built under conda, that is what I'll have to do.  I've not tried the [pinning Python](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) trick yet but I'll explore that.

Comment: @merv If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, mixing PyPI package installs with Conda is a bad idea, especially if one plans to update any of the packages in the env. The Anaconda team has a nice overview of the various pitfalls that one might encounter in the blog post, "[Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

## Options

### Create a new env

In line with their recommendations, and what personally has worked well in my experience, is to be liberal about creating new envs and, once a project's specs have been hardened, to limit new package installs and updates to only what is necessary (e.g., needed bug fixes, API updates, etc.).  I realize you explicitly said you'd prefer not to do this, but in my opinion it's the best option.

### Try other channels

Although this didn't pan out in your case, checking alternative channels, such as Conda Forge, could be useful (i.e., `-c conda-forge`). At the same time, I'd caution against simply searching Anaconda Cloud for an arbitrary channel that happens to have what you want. Only install from channels that you trust.

### Package pinning

Another option is to [try pinning the packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) you definitely don't want to change (e.g., `python=3.7.4`). This would force the dependency solver to figure out how to accomplish *exactly* what is requested in the question, and if it doesn't work, it be rather strong evidence that such a configuration is impossible with Conda packages alone.